# A complex log question

Tags: functions, complex-numbers

I'm trying to find the solutions of $\log(z)=i\log(\bar{z})$ where $\bar{z}$ is the conjugate of $z$. I'm aware of the multivalued complex log, so $\log(z)=\log|z|+i\arg(z)$ but I don't see to be getting anywhere,

any hints, hints only please, would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume we've made a branch cut to make life easy on ourselves and the argument ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$. Then what we have is $z = |z|e^{i\theta}$ and $\bar{z} = |z|e^{-i\theta}$. Then, $\log(z) = \log|z|+i\theta$ and $\log(\bar{z}) = \log|z|-i\theta$. Making appropriate substitutions, we get

$$\log|z|+i\theta = i(\log|z|-i\theta) = i\log|z|+\theta.$$

Try equating the real and imaginary parts from here and you'll get a nice solution. (Just read your bit about hints only!)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) if log|z|=θ what does that look like on the argand diagram? I'm having a tough time visualising it

Comment: We naturally like to work in $r$ and $\theta$ because circles are cool and all. How can you relate $\log|z|$ to $r$ and $\theta$? Once you have this relation, it might be good to check what Wolfram Alpha has to say on the matter.

Comment: log|z|=θ so |z|=e^θ and isn't |z| just r?

Comment: You got it :) Wolfram Alpha can handle these things very well..

Comment: If my answer is satisfactory, please accept it so that it doesn't keep getting bumped to the front page in the future.